# How can I add a link to the <i> tag?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-transitions

I try to style some  tags to get some good-looking social media buttons.

This is my current code:

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

/* General rule */

.dist {
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.button-big {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2em 0em 0.2em 0em;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Facebook class and animation */

.facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
  border: 1px solid #3B5998;
}
.facebook:hover {
  animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* YouTube class and animation */

.youtube {
  color: #bb0000;
  border: 1px solid #bb0000;
}
.youtube:hover {
  animation: youtubeAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: youtubeAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes youtubeAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes youtubeAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* Instagram class and animation */

.instagram {
  color: #125688;
  border: 1px solid #125688;
}
.instagram:hover {
  animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* link style */

.facebook a {
  color: #3B5998;
}
.youtube a {
  color: #bb0000;
}
.instagram a {
  color: #125688;
}
.facebook a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.youtube a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.instagram a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="facebook button-big">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="youtube button-big dist">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="instagram button-big dist">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
</div>
```

The problem is that the links is just on the icon, so when I hover the button a bit outside, the icon is style in the old color and not white. I hope you get what I mean, just have a look please.
How can I fix this the best way?

Comment: You can either add the classes to the anchor tag directly, or wrap the anchor tag with `<i>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate the `div`s in the `a` tags.
Add some styling to the `a` tag.

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

/* General rule */

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dist {
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.button-big {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2em 0em 0.2em 0em;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Facebook class and animation */

.facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
  border: 1px solid #3B5998;
}
.facebook:hover {
  animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* YouTube class and animation */

.youtube {
  color: #bb0000;
  border: 1px solid #bb0000;
}
.youtube:hover {
  animation: youtubeAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: youtubeAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes youtubeAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes youtubeAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* Instagram class and animation */

.instagram {
  color: #125688;
  border: 1px solid #125688;
}
.instagram:hover {
  animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* link style */

.facebook a {
  color: #3B5998;
}
.youtube a {
  color: #bb0000;
}
.instagram a {
  color: #125688;
}
.facebook a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.youtube a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.instagram a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
 <div class="facebook button-big">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
 </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
 <div class="youtube button-big dist">
  <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
 </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
 <div class="instagram button-big dist">
  <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
 </div>
</a>
```

Comment: @BenediktWinckler Accept the answer then :)

Comment: had to wait 8mins :)

Comment: @BenediktWinckler haha! I am glad that it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to change the links color when you hover the button, like this:

```
.facebook:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
.youtube:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
.instagram:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Full snippet:

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

/* General rule */

.dist {
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.button-big {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2em 0em 0.2em 0em;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Facebook class and animation */

.facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
  border: 1px solid #3B5998;
}
.facebook:hover {
  animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* YouTube class and animation */

.youtube {
  color: #bb0000;
  border: 1px solid #bb0000;
}
.youtube:hover {
  animation: youtubeAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: youtubeAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes youtubeAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes youtubeAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* Instagram class and animation */

.instagram {
  color: #125688;
  border: 1px solid #125688;
}
.instagram:hover {
  animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* link style */

.facebook a {
  color: #3B5998;
}
.youtube a {
  color: #bb0000;
}
.instagram a {
  color: #125688;
}
.facebook:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
.youtube:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
.instagram:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="facebook button-big">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="youtube button-big dist">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="instagram button-big dist">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

Try this code in your css:

```
.button-big:hover a i {
  color: #fff;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, you could just inherit animation:

```
.button-big a , a i {
 animation:inherit;
  }
```

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

/* General rule */

.dist {
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.button-big {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2em 0em 0.2em 0em;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Facebook class and animation */

.facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
  border: 1px solid #3B5998;
}
.facebook:hover {
  animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* YouTube class and animation */

.youtube {
  color: #bb0000;
  border: 1px solid #bb0000;
}
.youtube:hover {
  animation: youtubeAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: youtubeAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes youtubeAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes youtubeAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* Instagram class and animation */

.instagram {
  color: #125688;
  border: 1px solid #125688;
}
.instagram:hover {
  animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* link style */

.facebook a {
  color: #3B5998;
}
.youtube a {
  color: #bb0000;
}
.instagram a {
  color: #125688;
}
.facebook a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.youtube a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.instagram a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.button-big a , a i {
 animation:inherit;
  }
```

```html
<div class="facebook button-big">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="youtube button-big dist">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="instagram button-big dist">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
</div>
```

---

Or color

```
.button-big a , a i {
 color:inherit;
  }
```

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

/* General rule */

.dist {
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.button-big {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2em 0em 0.2em 0em;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Facebook class and animation */

.facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
  border: 1px solid #3B5998;
}
.facebook:hover {
  animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* YouTube class and animation */

.youtube {
  color: #bb0000;
  border: 1px solid #bb0000;
}
.youtube:hover {
  animation: youtubeAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: youtubeAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes youtubeAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes youtubeAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* Instagram class and animation */

.instagram {
  color: #125688;
  border: 1px solid #125688;
}
.instagram:hover {
  animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* link style */

.facebook a {
  color: #3B5998;
}
.youtube a {
  color: #bb0000;
}
.instagram a {
  color: #125688;
}
.facebook a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.youtube a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.instagram a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.button-big a , a i {
 color:inherit;
  }
```

```html
<div class="facebook button-big">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="youtube button-big dist">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="instagram button-big dist">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
</div>
```